# Use Raspberry Pi 3 with its camera module to live stream and also store that video on cloud

Tags: pi-3, python, camera, javascript

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 and camera module, I want to use that camera and live stream our internet and also store that video on cloud in chunks of specific time period (like store videos of 1 hour duration) using python or javascript. Currently, I am able to access the camera locally but I am not able to find any way to stream our internet.

Can any please guide me how I can do this, or suggest any library/package.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you could do that. Personally, I have used [Dataplicity](https://docs.dataplicity.com/docs/stream-live-video-from-your-pi) and it has worked pretty well.